# Why the HTTP request is sent incorrectly?

Tags: http, url, cross-browser, uri

Original URL Fragment: `{<>"|?(1)20416lol`

Encoded URL Fragment:

```
<code>encodeURIComponent('{<>"|?(1)20416lol')
-> %7B%3C%3E%22%7C%3F(1)20416lol</code>
```

But the HTTP GET request goes to another URL.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Comment: Please see screenshot. URL fragment in HTML is encoded correctly. But the browser sends to the server are not encoded value.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the moz dev network site on [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#Description)

Do the following to overwrite default encodeURIComponent function.

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*\|]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  })
}
```

Comment: Please see screenshot. URL fragment in HTML is encoded correctly. But the browser sends to the server are not encoded value.